# Trying in make insert query using cursor in django and can not get rid off this error TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: sql, sql-server, django, django-models

I am trying to make aan insert query using cursor in Django, but this error shows I searched for more than one solution but nothing helped the error is:
sql = sql % tuple('?' * len(params))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

I tried to use '%s' instead of '?' but it didn't work

```py
def insert_DTARFDE2003SYD0827(sourcePE,sourceInterFace,targetPE,targetInterFace):
    params = (sourcePE, sourceInterFace,targetPE,targetInterFace)
    if sourcePE!=None and sourceInterFace!=None and targetPE!=None and targetInterFace!=None:
        sql=" insert into DTA.RFDE2003SYD0827 values ( '?','?',NULL,NULL,NULL,'?','?' "
        with connections['DataAdmin'].cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(sql,params)
```

My databases:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'Fileade',
        'HOST': '10.238.76.53',
        'USER': 'SDS_dataflow',
        
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        }
    
    } ,

    'DataAdmin': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'Data_Admin',
        'HOST': '10.238.76.53',
        'USER': 'SDS_dataflow',
        
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        }
}  

}
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mohammed\Envs\TestEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Mohammed\Envs\TestEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Mohammed\Envs\TestEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\College\Orange Training\MassiveMigrationPortalTool\posts\views.py", line 137, in preStepBtn1
    insert_DTARFDE2003SYD0827(sourcePE,targetPE,sourceInterFace,targetInterFace)
  File "D:\College\Orange Training\MassiveMigrationPortalTool\posts\views.py", line 36, in insert_DTARFDE2003SYD0827
    cursor.execute(sql,params)
  File "C:\Users\Mohammed\Envs\TestEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Mohammed\Envs\TestEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\Mohammed\Envs\TestEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Mohammed\Envs\TestEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Mohammed\Envs\TestEnv\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 542, in execute
    sql = self.format_sql(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Mohammed\Envs\TestEnv\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 510, in format_sql
    sql = sql % tuple('?' * len(params))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback, and also specify which db-api connector you're using (pyodbc, pymssql, other ?). But in all cases, for a db-api compliant connector, placeholders are NOT supposed to be quoted (it's the db-api connector's duty to take care of proper quoting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error happens in the `django-pyodbc` database adapter (those are the modules that bridges Django models with various db-api connectors).

[As explicitely mentioned in the FineManual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#connections-and-cursors), when using Django database adapters, **you must use the `%s` placeholder**, whatever the underlying db-api connector expects - which is why django-pyodbc tries to replace `%s` placeholders (expected by the django db adapter api) with `?` (expected by the underlying `pyodbc` db-api connector).

The solution is obvious: use the expected `%s` placeholder.

Now you mention:

> I tried to use '%s' instead of '?' but it didn't work

Note that "didn't work" is the most useless description of an issue - you should have explained exactly **how** it "didn't work".

But anyway: as also explicitely mentionned [in django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw) and (much less explicitely, I have to say) in [pyodbc doc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Getting-started#parameters) and [the db-api specs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle), **you must NOT quote the placeholders !!!** - which is why your attempt at using `'%s'` failed too.

To make a long story short: your SQL query should be:

```
sql = "insert into DTA.RFDE2003SYD0827 values (%s, %s, NULL, NULL, NULL, %s, %s)"
```